# How to build library using cmake in windows

Tags: windows, cmake, static-libraries

I have written a library MyLib and I want to write CMakeLists to enable users build the library using cmake in both Linux and Windows system. MyLib contains folders like bin, include, lib and src. I know cmake can generate VS solution files in Windows, and the users can build it in VS to generate .lib files. But when I tried it, the .lib files are always under a folder named "debug". What should I do if I want the .lib files go under MyLib/lib when the user builds the solution?

I am a newbie in cmake and I really hope someone can help me on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio projects provide both Debug and Release version in the same CMake build tree, as opposed to Unix make or nmake projects, where the config Debug or Release is passed to cmake when generating the Makefiles using the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`. That's why you have a Debug folder, i.e. because the Visual Studio build tree can be used for both debug and release. If you want to have on windows a similar experience as on Unix, just use the generator for NMake Makefiles

Comment: @rcomblen: Thanks. I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a target property for your library:

```
set_property(TARGET mylib PROPERTY LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${OUTPUT_DIR})
```

See CMake docs for more infos:

- [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aLIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)
- [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_< CONFIG >](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aLIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG)